# how to fix error: "the prelaunchtask 'c/c++: gcc build active file' terminated with exit code -1"

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - Visual Studio Code

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccfkk.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndUOR.png)

how to fix this error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use special shell characters in your file names. `&` is special, so `C&Cpp` will bite you, again and again and again and again AND AGAIN AND AGAIN.

Special shell characters in filenames are *not* illegal, and you *can* use them if you really want to, but...

The alternative is to fix *all* of your shell scripts and config files and whatnot such that all user-provided strings such as file names and parameters and everything else are properly escaped. This is hard. Not using `&` is easy. Your choice.